# Loading static web pages into a div of main page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load some static web pages into a div of my index page. I am using jQuery.

My code is as follows:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $("ul.css-tabs").tabs("div.css-panes > div", { effect: 'ajax' });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#org1").click(function() {
            $('#result').load('/IEI/WebContent/org.html');
        }); 

        $("#local1").click(function() {
            $('#result').load('localC.html');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<li>    
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="org1">Organization</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="local1">Local Centre</a></li>
        <div id="result" style="clear: both;"></div>
```

But somehow its not working. Cannot get the glitch.

Comment: can you put brouser console result ?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+I and tell us wat error u getting....dis will work only on chrome browser

Comment: Did the jquery load? Are you on http or https?

Comment: The code looks ok for the load statements, you will likely want to move the ul.css-tabs statement into the document ready handler too. What errors are showing in your browser console?

Comment: I got my mistake a function above this was causing the error ,anyway thnx for help.